# ActionScript3 when fullscreen doesn't react

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, fullscreen

I've go a strange problem in my AS3 project. When going into fullscreen the communication seems to hang up. No HTTP requests are sent to the server, loaders have problems with loading assets, even those from browser's cache.

What's even more surprising is the fact that it doesn't happen every time but only sometimes on local version of the game. When then game is deployed on the outer servers and one start using it from a website it has those problems listed above.

I initialize fullscreen mode it such way:

```
gameStage.quality = StageQuality.MEDIUM;
gameStage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
```

and before I set also this properties:

```
gameStage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
gameStage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

I've got no idea what can be possibly wrong, espacially it doesn't happen on my local versions of the same game. I've googled a lot for a solution but nothing seemes to work. I'll appreaciate every possible help sooner than better cause I'm in quite of hurry to deploy the game.

Answer (score 1):

You've got yourself a [security issue](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c5d.html). You should always use the [content debugger version of Flash Player](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) and/or [configure mm.cfg](http://jpauclair.net/2010/02/10/mmcfg-treasure/) to see any error messages.

Also, note that [FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE](http://help.adobe.com/de_DE/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageDisplayState.html#FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE) is only supported by AIR applications.

Comment: I used heavily the debugger to see what can be the problem and my mm.cfg has the highest error setting I could possibly set. The second part is indeed strange because I've built the fullscreen part of my app from a sample found in the Web and they used FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE, so it seems strange, bu I'll test it, thanks.

Comment: Have you added try..catch blocks to prevent security error messages in your code?  It does make a difference, btw if you're using the debugger player locally, or if you've installed the content debugger plugin in your browser. The "regular" plugin doesn't show alert windows.

Comment: We have implemented Errbit error reporting in the game and test it in a global try...catch. I also thought this can be a problem, but logs shown nothing. Thanks for the second aid, I've no idea that it makes such a difference.